# How to change a video perspective with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am trying to learn about changing the personal perspective of my videos. I found a command form below. It is perfect with the show. But I want to change it to my liking. I don't understand how the coordinates work because just changing part of it makes the video distorted and incomplete. Can anybody explain it to me. For example I want a larger video with size 520: 350 for example.
    [0:v]setpts=PTS/1.0,scale=395:333,pad=”iw+4:ih+4:2:2:0x00000000″,perspective=00:-130:440:00:00:445:440:360 [v1]; [1:v][v1]overlay=shortest=1:x=438:y=128,setdar=16/9

If there's an easy explanation, that's too great. Thanks for care.

Comment: Have you read the docs for the filter: http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#perspective

Comment: I have read it and really very confusing.